# Accessing Advanced Custom Fields by Page Name

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to retrieve all advanced custom fields tied to a particular page. This is different than iterating through posts, I am familiar with the following:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'     => 'post_name',
    'meta_key'      => 'color',
    'meta_value'    => 'red'
));
```

However this method is specific to posts and does not allow me to retrieve all ACF by page name.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are too ways to do this that come to mind...

## 1. Using the Loop

Using WP_Query you can do something like this...

```
<?php

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'pagename'               => 'homepage',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_field( "field_name" ); 
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

In place of the 'homepage' in `'pagename' => 'homepage'`, you want to put the page slug of your page. And of course in place of `the_field( "text_field" );` you want to add your fields/content.

You can also query by Page ID and some other parameters. You can find all other parameters that you can use here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

## 2. Adding second parameter to the_field() function

More simple way, without custom loop, is just to use ACF's built-in `the_field()` function with the `$post->ID` parameter added as a second parameter.

```
<?php the_field('field_name', 123);
```

This might be the way to go since you want to show the content of only one page, and therefore don't really need to loop.

Reference: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/

Answer (score 0):

You can use ACF's `get_fields()` function -

```
<?php $fields = get_fields( $post->ID ); ?>
```

You could then loop through them or simply print the array for testing.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/